# How do I return a count of linked objects in a GenericRelation field in a DRF Serializer?

Tags: django-rest-framework

There are a number of questions about [serializing GenericRelations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310400/how-to-serialize-a-genericrelation-in-django) in Django Rest Framework however I have a use case where I want to simply return the count of objects in the GenericRelation field only and not serialize them. The documentation and existing questions I can find do not cover this.

I thought it might be as simple as returning the `len(value)` in a custom Serializer, however that produces the following throw:

```
object of type 'GenericRelatedObjectManager' has no len()
```

My failed attempt:

```
class ObjectCountSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
    """
    Return the count of related objects.
    """

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return len(value)

class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Main serializers for the writings module
    """
    author = MemberListSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    comments = ObjectCountSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'id',
            'slug',
            'url',
            'title',
            'description',
            'created',
            'edited',
            'author',
            'comments'
        )
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

How do I simply return the count of objects in the relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a `SerializerMethodField` would solve this, e.g.

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Main serializers for the writings module
    """
    author = MemberListSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_comments(self, instance):
        return instance.comments.count()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'id',
            'slug',
            'url',
            'title',
            'description',
            'created',
            'edited',
            'author',
            'comments'
        )
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

`SerializerMethodField` is a read-only field that returns the result of a method, generally named `get_<field_name>`.

Comment: Bingo bango bongo, that's got it. Cheers mate, thanks for the assist.

Comment: Haha, that sounded very Australian.  Glad it helped :)